# Ejabberd limits online users count at 64,464. Descriptors already increased

Tags: linux, process, erlang, ejabberd, tsung

I am being restricted to bring more than roughly 64000 (64,464 precisely) users online on an Ejabberd node. I am using xml script (Tsung) to bring the users online on the node.

I have raised the limit of descriptors already:

```
Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
1> os:cmd("ulimit -n").
"1045000\n"
```

One weird observation is this (expect available port count as integer value here):

```
2> os:getenv("ERL_MAX_PORTS").
false
```

Besides, the "ERL_MAX_PORTS" in the ejabberdctl.cfg file is set to 704500.

```
ERL_MAX_PORTS=704500
```

I guess One Ejabberd node has some limit for maximum users to be online. This could be memory dependent on the machine or something.

Additonally, this is how the /etc/security/limits.conf looks:

```
#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50   
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
root             soft    nofile          1045000
root             hard    nofile          1045000
```

I can give a try by creating another Virtual host runing on the same Linux machine as:

```
hosts:
  - "devlab"
  - "devlab2"
```

But i am not sure how this would be any different.

Pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: check your /var/log/syslog information.

Comment: This is all i have on my systme.

[root@Test ~]# cd /var/log/syslog
-bash: cd: /var/log/syslog: No such file or directory 

[root@Test ~]# find / -name syslog
/etc/logrotate.d/syslog

Comment: tail -f /var/log/syslog

Comment: No such file exists at the location. Im ust mention, i am using RHEL 6.

[root@Test bin]# tail -f /var/log/syslog
tail: cannot open `/var/log/syslog' for reading: No such file or directory

Okay, i guessi need to look into /var/log/messages somewhere.

Comment: check your os's /var/log directory and understand it. check os's sysctl.conf file and it control the OS's limit.

Comment: This is what i could see in the file you mentioned:

# Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
kernel.msgmnb = 65536

# Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
kernel.msgmax = 65536

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
fs.file-max = 1045000

Anything of concern?

Comment: redhat's os limit (not only user session limit) http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Comment: redhat's syslog https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/2.1/html/Cluster_Manager_Installation_and_Administration/s1-software-syslog.html

Comment: I think you'd better to understand the redhat's log system, it is helpful for you to solve the problem. I am not familar with this os's syslog log.

Comment: what is the erlang process limit and ets max tables set for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the os' port limit, you have to configure the erlang port limit as well. This can be done by starting the erlang vm with the +Q argument ([further information](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html)).

> +Q Number|legacy
>   Sets the maximum number of simultaneously existing ports for this system if a Number is passed as value. Valid range for Number is [1024-134217727]

For example: erl +Q 704500

You can check the erlang port limit by using the following command in the eshell:

```
erlang:system_info(port_limit)
```